# Is there some rule to derive a sum of $x$, with lower and upper bounds depending on $x$?

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

I like to know a rule to derivate this:

$$ g(x) = \sum_{t=a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)$$
$$ a(x) < b(x) $$
$$ a(x), b(x) \in \mathbb{Z} $$
I already tried the chain rule (like in the Leibniz integral rule):

$$ h(a(x),b(x),x) = \sum_{t=a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) $$

$$\frac{d}{dx}h = \frac{\partial h}{\partial a} \frac{da}{dx}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial b} \frac{db}{dx}+\sum_{t=a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)$$

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you saying that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are integers, for any $x$?

Comment: Yep! I forgot to say so!

Comment: It is not clear why the function is differentiable. $a,b$ are in general discontinuous functions

Comment: I was thinking in this like a interpolation. Such as the gamma function is a interpolation for the factorial function.

Comment: I have tried to answer the question, making two assumptions : 1) That both $a$ and $b$ are differentiable; 2) that the domain of them both is a connected open set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both differentiable (which I think is reasonable to assume in this context), they are continuous. If the domain of $a$ (similarly for $b$ as well) is some connected open set of $\mathbb{R}$, or in particular $\mathbb{R}$ itself, then we get that the image is also connected, and as the image is a subset of integers, it should be constant.

Thus we have that both $a$ and $b$ are constants, and can be treated as such while differentiating.

ie, $$ g'(x) = \sum_{t = a}^b \frac{ \partial }{\partial x} f(x,t)$$

Comment: Nice tried, but this is a trivial solution. I am looking for solutions like whem $b(x)=x$ and $a(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Well, if $b(x) =x$, it won't be an integer, unless you restrict your domain to a subset of integers, in which case it's not clear to me how you are going to differentiate.

Comment: You are right. If $b(x)=ceil(x)$? In this case, is there something?

Comment: Won't it be discontinuous then? I can't see any nice enough formula like you suggested holding then, atleast on the points of discontinuity of $b$ (or $a$) for the simple fact that their derivatives can't exist..